# An exception occurred while executing 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, load-data-infile

I have all previleges to the mysql user for the database but still getting below error

> [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
>   An exception occurred while executing 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/uk_insiders/tfo.uktrades_transaction_code.out' IGNORE INTO TABLE uktrades_transaction_codes FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' (id,description)':
>
> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden in /Symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php line 138
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>   Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden in /Symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php line 138

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the same exception message.
I was able to perform this by using PDO dirtectly.

Comment: I am not able to do, look like some pdo_driver issue. I am using symfony 2 so would like to make it work through doctrine only.

Comment: The only workaround I found was PDO only:
`//get the connection
$cnx = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();
$stmt = $cnx->prepare('LOAD DATA LOCAL ...');
$stmt->execute();
`
For information, I worked on Symfony2 and Doctrine2 too. And this worked for me.

Comment: This is how I am doing it right now which is giving me above error.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem...
I solve it by replace:

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...

by

> LOAD DATA INFILE

*Local option:
When this switch is specified the input file will be read from the host the MySQL client is running on instead of the MySQL server. When this switch is not specified, the input file will be read from the data directory on the MySQL host. To use LOAD DATA without the LOCAL switch, the connected user must have the "FILE" privilege.(http://geekology.co.za/article/2010/02/how-to-import-or-export-csv-or-text-files-to-from-mysql-databases)*

Answer (score 2):

I had tried to pass PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE parameter through doctrine configuration options parameter, but did not work, This is the solution finally working for me.

```
    $dbhost = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('database_host');
    $dbuser = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('database_user');
    $dbpass = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('database_password');
    $connParams = $em->getConnection()->getParams();

    $pdoConn = new \PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbhost . ';dbname=' . $connParams['dbname'], $dbuser, $dbpass, array(
        \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true
    ));

    $sql = "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0";
    $stmt = $pdoConn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file' IGNORE INTO TABLE $tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' $columns";

    $stmt = $pdoConn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Do you know if it is even possible to set this at the Doctrine level or whether the situation has changed since you asked the question?

Answer (score 0):

The two working answers are workaround :

- The accepted answer proposes to use a PDO connection
- Another answer proposes to remove the LOCAL keyword, but it's not always possible

A third, clean solution, is to enable the LOCAL option in Doctrine, but it is a bit tricky :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24759583/425204

Note : this requires also that LOCAL is enabled in MySQL config on the server : my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

To enable the `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE` option for PDO object in Symfony, we can add it into the yml config:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        options:
            !php/const PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE: true
        # Skip the rest
```

Also note how to reference PHP constant here in yml file, and this format is used for Symfony 3.4. For older version, check out Symfony [doc](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-php-constants-in-yaml-files).