# Symfony2 Doctrine PDO MySQL Connection with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

Why i have this problem?

```
Warning: PDO::query(): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden in /srv/www/project/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php on line 742
```

Thats my configuration.

```
#app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        options:
            "\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE": true

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
```

I tried the options without leading `\`.

AND if i use this, it works great!

```
/* @var \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection $connection */
$dbhost = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('database_host');
$dbuser = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('database_user');
$dbpass = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('database_password');
$dbname = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('database_name');

$connection = new \PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbhost . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass, array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true));
```

**How i can use doctrine from symfony2 instead the own new \PDO $connection.**

I dont know why doctrine ignore the options... Or cant Doctrine convert the options to the Constant/Integer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tried and solved.

```
#app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        options:
            1001: true

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
```

**Doctrine options shouldnt be a constant ^^**

*Use 1001 instead `"\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE"` fixed the problem.*