# Symfony config: Doctrine InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized option "options" under "doctrine.dbal"

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using Symfony 2 and want to import a local CSV file with Doctrine:

```
$connection = $this->entityManager->getConnection();

        $output->writeln('Importing Articles');

        $path = $this->importHelperService->getCSVBasePath() . 'PromotionArtikel.csv';

        $query =
            <<<EOF
                LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$path' INTO TABLE ProductCSV
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                ENCLOSED BY '"'
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
                IGNORE 1 LINES;
EOF;

        $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
```

But I got

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>   Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden

So I search how can I fix this problem and found this:

[Symfony2 Doctrine PDO MySQL Connection with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757896/symfony2-doctrine-pdo-mysql-connection-with-load-data-local-infile)

But when I try to put the options into my config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        options:
            1001: true
```

I got an InvalidConfigurationException:

> InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized option "options" under
>   "doctrine.dbal"

In my composer.lock I search for doctrine/dbal and I can see that version 2.5.12 is installed.

> "name": "doctrine/dbal",
>               "version": "v2.5.12",

Anyone an idea how can I solve this problem?

**EDIT: Found by myself:**

> In my config there are different connections. So in this case the
>   "options" have to be configured in the default connection:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                options:
                    1001: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection options should be defined at `dbal.connections.<connection-name>.options` according to the [DoctrineBundle 2.5 configuration docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.5/reference/configuration/doctrine.html):

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                options:
                    # an array of options
                    key:                  []
```