# Big database - doctrine query slow even with index

Tags: mysql, performance, csv, doctrine, symfony4

I'm building an app with Symfony 4 + Doctrine, where people can upload big CSV files and those records then get stored in a database. Before inserting, I'm checking that the entry doesn't already exist...

On a sample CSV file with only 1000 records, it takes 16 seconds without an index and **8 seconds** with an index (MacBook 3Ghz - 16 GB Memory). My intuition tells me, this is quite slow and should be done in under < 1 sec especially with the index.

The index is set on the email column.

My code:

```
$ssList = $this->em->getRepository(EmailList::class)->findOneBy(["id" => 1]);    

foreach ($csv as $record) {
     $subscriber_exists = $this->em->getRepository(Subscriber::class)
        ->findOneByEmail($record['email']);

    if ($subscriber_exists === NULL) {
        $subscriber = (new Subscriber())
            ->setEmail($record['email'])
            ->setFirstname($record['first_name'])
            ->addEmailList($ssList)
        ;

        $this->em->persist($subscriber);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

My Question:

How can I speed up this process?

Comment: `flush()` outside of your loop, you're doing a lot of operations instead of readying the entity manager

Comment: Should `getRepository` be pulled out of the loop?  Is that where it connects to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Use [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847842/doctrine-dbal-and-load-data-local-infile).

[LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) has `IGNORE` and `REPLACE` options for handling duplicates if you put a `UNIQUE KEY` or `PRIMARY KEY` on your `email` column.

[Look at settings](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83125/mysql-any-way-to-import-a-huge-32-gb-sql-dump-faster) for making the import faster.

Comment: Thank you Dan. I will have a look into it and report back if it is faster! :)

Answer (score 0):

Like Cid said, move the flush() outside of the loop or put a batch counter inside the loop and only flush inside of it at certain intervals

```
$batchSize = 1000;
$i = 1;
foreach ($csv as $record) {
     $subscriber_exists = $this->em->getRepository(Subscriber::class)
        ->findOneByEmail($record['email']);

    if ($subscriber_exists === NULL) {
        $subscriber = (new Subscriber())
            ->setEmail($record['email'])
            ->setFirstname($record['first_name'])
            ->addEmailList($ssList)
        ;

        $this->em->persist($subscriber);
        if (  ($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
            $this->em->flush();
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
$this->em->flush();
```

Or if that's still slow, you could grab the Connection `$this->em->getConnection()` and use DBAL as stated here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.8/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#insert

Comment: Thanks! I put the flush() outside the loop without noticing a significant performance boost. I think I might go with raw SQL in the end and see if that is faster. I will report back as soon as I dug more into it. Thanks!